# Want to change DateTimePicker.Value.TimeOfDay, but it is read only

Tags: c#, datetimepicker, readonly, timeofday

I am trying to check an entered time in a DateTimePicker control and correct it to the closest acceptable value in C#

```
if (Summer1.Value.TimeOfDay > Summer2.Value.TimeOfDay)
                Summer1.Value.TimeOfDay = Summer2.Value.TimeOfDay;
```

It gives me the following:

> Property or indexer 'System.DateTime.TimeOfDay' cannot be assigned to
>   -- it is read only

Why does it handle the DateTimePicker object as a system time?
I could not find anything related to Read-Only state of the control in VS 2003.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Summer1.Value` is the property of `DateTimePicker` and it has type of `DateTime`. This property is assignable.

You're trying to assign `Summer1.Value.TimeOfDay` - which is a property of `DateTime` object `Summer1.Value` - and this property does not have setter in `DateTime` class.

```
Summer1.Value = Summer2.Value
```

should work fine but may not give you the desired result.

The closest to your desirable output will be something like

```
Summer1.Value = Summer1.Value.Date + Summer2.Value.TimeOfDay;
```

Comment: Summer1.Value = Summer2.Value worked well for me. Bolshoe spasibo.